# How to get domain name from a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I need a help of you. I want to split domain name from a string in my C# application.
Any idea about that.

eg : `string strURL="http://stackoverflow.com/questions";`

and I need output like 
DomainName : stackoverflow.com

Comment: This question has been asked a 1000 times already. Put a little effort in your search abilities.

Comment: A quick google gave many viable answers to this.

Comment: Hi juergen, Please refer some links for me to find the best solution

Answer (score 7):

This should work.

> new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions").DnsSafeHost

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Regex....

```
            string domainName = string.Empty;
            string strURL="http://stackoverflow.com/questions";
            Regex rg = new Regex("://(?<host>([a-z\\d][-a-z\\d]*[a-z\\d]\\.)*[a-z][-a-z\\d]+[a-z])");
            if (rg.IsMatch(strURL))
            {
                domainName = rg.Match(strURL).Result("${host}");
            }
```

domainName gives the domain name.....

Comment: Thank you Akash, please check this for url like www.google.co.in/somthing ... like subdomains also.